# java sql syntax error with createStatement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have an sql table `sysuser` looking like this:

`id (pk)` `email` `password` `role`

I'd like to insert values into the table. I get the data in `ArrayList<String>`:

```
cell 0 no value,
cell 1 ID,
cell 2 email,
cell 3 password,
cell 4 role,
```

Here is the code i've written:

```
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO sysuser VALUES ('"+string.get(1)+"', '"+ string.get(2) +"','"+ string.get(3) +"','"+string.get(4)+"'");
```

where string is the `ArrayList<String>`.

The code is not working and I can't figure why. It works perfectly with another query. I get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

I read about prepared statments but I did not understand the syntax. I know that it is not safe to insert data directly, yet for this specific query it doesn't matter.

Comment: Can you show a sample value that is passed to stmt.executeUpdate()

Comment: Also what are the field types in sysuser table?

Comment: You should *certainly* use a PreparedStatement for this task, instead of concatenating values into the SQL string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a `)`

```
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO sysuser " + 
                    "VALUES ('" + string.get(1) + "','"+ 
                                  string.get(2) + "','"+ 
                                  string.get(3) + "','"+
                                  string.get(4) + "')");
                                                    ^------------here
```

And if you are not filling all columns of your table you should provide a list of columns you are inserting into like this

```
INSERT INTO sysuser (col_name_1, col_name2, col_name5, col_name7)
VALUES (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! i went crazy!!! Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Try to print first the sql this statement produces.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO sysuser VALUES ('"+string.get(1)+"', '"+ string.get(2) +"','"+ string.get(3) +"','"+string.get(4)+"'";
System.out.println(sql);
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Then run in your favorite SQL tool and check what error it gives.
And post both results here. :)

Later check this link: [Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java)